# Bing Maps REST get shortest route

Tags: vb.net, rest, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I am using an older version of Bing Maps REST service. Currently, distance calculation uses the recommended routes around the M25 but I am looking to make this use the shortest distance through London instead (not as the crow flies). I assume there is a way to do this by passing a parameter but I'm not sure what, how, where etc...

Just to make this worse... it is coded in VB.

I can't seem to find any documentation for this either so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with VB, use the Bing Maps .NET REST Toolkit. It works with C# and VB, simply add the NuGet package to your project: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit

As for getting the shortest route, set the optimize property to ShortestDistance.